# Can I selectively update rows based on existence of duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Database: MySql 5.6.x

I have a table that I want to update rows in two different ways.

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME       ║ TYPE ║ STATUS ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ fred       ║ A    ║        ║
║ 2  ║ barney     ║ B    ║        ║
║ 3  ║ wilma      ║ B    ║        ║
║ 4  ║ fred       ║ B    ║        ║
║ 5  ║ fred       ║ C    ║        ║
║ 6  ║ Betty      ║ A    ║        ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

There is a unique constraint on the table (name, type)

I want to update the non-duplicating 'fred' records with name='barney'
and soft delete (update status column) any records that would be duplicates.

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME       ║ TYPE ║ STATUS ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ barney     ║ A    ║        ║
║ 2  ║ barney     ║ B    ║        ║
║ 3  ║ wilma      ║ B    ║        ║
║ 4  ║ fred       ║ B    ║  DEL   ║
║ 5  ║ barney     ║ C    ║        ║
║ 6  ║ Betty      ║ A    ║        ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Can this be done in a single sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.type = t2.type AND t2.name = 'barney'
SET t1.name = CASE 
              WHEN t2.name IS NULL THEN 'barney'
              ELSE t1.name
           END,
    t1.status = CASE 
                WHEN t2.name IS NULL THEN t2.status
                ELSE 'DEL'
             END
WHERE t1.name = 'fred';
```

The idea is to use a `LEFT JOIN` operation: a matching record indicates a duplicate had the `UPDATE` taken place.

Hence:

- If `t2.name IS NULL` there is no match and `UPDATE` can change `name` field. `status` remains unchanged in this case.
- If `t2.name IS NOT NULL` there is a match, so `name` remains unchanged and `status` gets updated to `'DEL'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff9ffc/1)

Comment: This is a slam dunk!  Works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single statement.  To answer your specific question:

```
update t
    set name = (case when id = 4 then name else 'barney' end),
        status = (case when id = 4 then 'DEL' else status end)
    where t.name = 'fred';
```

Comment: Thank you for responding...I want to update all the "fred" records though, I don't know the IDs of these records...can I do this by 'name' instead of by id?

Comment: so that if changing the record 'name' column to 'barney' would result in a duplicate, change the status column to 'DEL' instead.